# How to launch Android's Native MediaPlayer from a webpage?

Tags: android, stream, mp3, audio-streaming, shoutcast

I would like to create a webpage for my Shoutcast stream the launches Android's native media player. I found an example here >> http://s4.viastreaming.net/8000/mobile/

My question is "What is the code the makes this possible for Android?"

Comment: Nate - your abusive replies (deleted) are unwarranted. Please be specific in *what way* you think they are missing your question, but leave the flames at home.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, there is no way to launch any intent (including the music player) from a webpage.

That page streams music to the browser and lets the OS decide what to do with it. It will be up to each user what application uses to listen to it. You will have no control of it.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need any code. just return a object of type audio/mpeg, perhaps a mp3 file and android will handle it by opening its media player!

Answer (score 0):

The Android browser attempts to be smart about some types of media.  If it detects embedded media that it knows how to handle, it will launch a chooser (or the default player).

This behavior may have confused you into thinking that the web page itself is actually launching the media player app, it isn't, it's just the browser being smart.

On Android, applications such as the media player are launched using Intents.  As Aleadam has said, you can't make a webpage launch an intent.